# How to configure IIS to handle static files only if they exist. ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ASP.NET Core Controller that listens on this url: `/banners/graphical/{imageName}`
Whenever a new request comes in, say with [imageName] img.jpg and a file that is called `"/banners/graphical/img.jpg"` is not found on the file system, the controller gets the file from some other place and puts it on the files system and then returns it.

If the file already exists, the web server returns it without invoking the controller. This works... in development... it works when Kestrel serves the requests because `app.UseStaticFiles()` is called before `app.Mvc()`. It works by default when I use IIS Express from Visual Studio... on the production IIS I get 404 error.

What settings do I need to use on the production IIS so that I can achieve the desired functionality?

This is my `Web.config` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>

  <!--
    Configure your application settings in appsettings.json. Learn more at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=786380
  -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false"
                stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: you need to create a rewrite rule on IIS...check [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2017/Apr/27/IIS-and-ASPNET-Core-Rewrite-Rules-for-AspNetCoreModule)

Comment: I have the same problem with ASP.NET Core 2. I tried  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite [GitHub link](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/dev/samples/RewriteSample/Startup.cs), but without success. I have trouble with pages, that contains ID as a string with '.' dots like 'localhost:8080/localization/detail/this.is.my.localization.key'.

Comment: I did the check on application level. Wasn't able to solve this